# Abstract Algebra help

Tags: abstract-algebra

Recall that a subgroup N of a group G is called characteristic if F(N)=N for all automorphisms F of G. If N is a characteristic subroup of G, show that N is a normal subgroup of G.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Do you have any thoughts on the problem that you can share? Regards

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

An inner automorphism is...well, yes: an automorphism. What does it mean $\,N\,$ is invariable under *any* such inner automorphism?

Note: an inner automorphism $\,I_x\,$ is of the form $\,I_x(g):=g^x:=x^{-1}gx\;,\;\;x,g\in G\,$

Answer (score 1):

Recall that for every $g\in G$ the map $F_g:G\rightarrow G$ given by $F_g(x)=gxg^{-1}$ is an automorphism of $G$. So, if $N$ is characteristic, then $F_g(N)=N$ whenever $g\in G$. But this means $gng^{-1}\in N$ whenever $g\in G$ and $n\in N$. Hence $N$ is normal.